# TypeError: images.forEach is not a function while using react-slick in Firefox 47.0

Tags: reactjs, react-slick

I am using [react-slick](https://github.com/akiran/react-slick) for implementing carousel in React.
The carousel works fine in Chrome.
However, in Firefox (47.0) it gives an error: "TypeError: images.forEach is not a function".
[image: Error Image]

I tried to have only image tags inside the react slick slider like the below code:

```
<Slider {...settings} className={classes.slider}>
                <div className={classes.sliderdiv}>
                        <img  src="..."/>
                </div>
                <div className={classes.sliderdiv}>
                        <img  src="..."/>
                </div>
                <div className={classes.sliderdiv}>
                        <img  src="..."/>
                </div></Slider>
```

However, still I am getting the same error in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was present in react-slick version 0.21.0.
Updated the version to new one(0.22.3) and the issue is resolved.
Also, refer to [this](https://github.com/akiran/react-slick/issues/1138) issue.